# .Net MAUI WinUI push notification opening new instance

Tags: c#, windows, push-notification, maui

Every click on a push notification received opens a new instance of the app.

The documentation and many other samples that I found use the following code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active.
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page.
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application.
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window.
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter.
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active.
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

But this is not working for me. The following line is causing a NullReferenceException on **Window.Current.Content**.

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

I also noticed that my App class is inheriting from MauiWinUIApplication, and I think this is the point. Maybe this MauiWinUIApplication has a different way to deal with this problem but I can't find:

```
public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication
```

How to prevent opening new instance every time a push notification is clicked?

I'm using:
Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.0,
Maui .Net 6

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about this topic, but are you sure that is `WinUI 3` code, not older WinUI / UWP code?  Anyway, I found [this WindowsAppSDK-Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Notifications/App/CsUnpackagedAppNotifications) that might be relevant.

Comment: NOTE: In your code, click `MauiWinUIApplication`, then F12 to go to its declaration. You will see `public abstract class MauiWinUIApplication : Application, IPlatformApplication`. `Application` is `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application`, so AFAIK it will work the same as any other `WinUI 3` app (Windows Desktop App).

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `WinUI` in `.Net Maui` is to allow **multiple instances** of your app to run which will give us a lot of problems for various reasons such as a SQLite database, or deep linking etc. And this is `known issue` that's being tracked in [Simplify and make more robust the process for Single-instance WinUI apps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9973).

As an alternative workaround, you can refer to [Making the app single-instanced](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2022/01/28/making-the-app-single-instanced-part-3/)  on how to make the app `single-instanced` which will prevent opening new instance every time a push notification is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alexander, but the solution from WindowsBlog didn't work for me. Navigating through this github issue you mentioned, I found a workaround on this post: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2121) from wbokkers:
[link](https://gist.github.com/wbokkers/af326da5391bdb13b58529e720540178) where I was able to check if is "FirstLaunch" or not but I don't know what to do next, how to raise my MainPage since **Window.Current.Content** is not working on Maui.